# javascript link to url for metro buttons

Tags: javascript

Im using this, http://jqmetro.codeplex.com/ but cant get it to work. Instead of alert message i would like go to page.

Thank you,

```
 $("#metroaqui").AddMetroDoubleButton('bt4', 'metro-azul', 'Style/Imagem/carta.png', '4', 'alert("this is a alert message");');
```

in the javascript:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.AddMetroSimpleButton = function (id, theme, imagem, texto, link) {
        var el = $(this);
        var html_code = "<div";
        if (id != '') {
            html_code += " id='" + id + "'";
        }
        if (link != '') {
            html_code += " onclick='" + link + "'";
        }
        html_code += " class='metro-btn metro metrosingle " + theme + "'>\r\n";
        html_code += "\t<div class='imgsimple'><img src='" + imagem + "' alt='" + texto + "' /></div>\r\n";
        html_code += "\t<span>" + texto + "</span>\r\n";
        html_code += "</div>\r\n";

        el.append(html_code);
    };
```

Comment: You just have to change your function.. Is that what is not working? Did you try it?

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made this correction it goes to page url

```
if (link != '') {
            html_code += " onclick=window.location='" + link + "'";
        }
```